# Override CollectionProxy find method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

What's the correct way to override ActiveRecord's `find` so that it behaves the same way when used on a model class(like `Comment.find(1)`) and collection(like `post.comments.find(1)`)?

Let's take these two simple models as an example:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post

  def self.find(*args)
    puts 'Overridden find called!'
    super
  end
end
```

With classes like these, `Comment.find(1)` correctly uses overridden method but `post.comments.find(1)` still uses original version of `find`.
I'm aware that I could override `#find` in `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` but I don't like this solution because it affects every model in the application. Could you suggest a correct solution?

EDIT:
What I want to achieve is:

```
Comment.find(1) # prints 'Overridden find called'
some_post.comments.find(1) # prints 'Overridden find called'
Post.find(1) # does NOT print 'Overridden find called', calls regular find
```

Comment: Can you define the behavior you're expecting? `Comment.find` and `post.comments.find` both take an ID argument and return a single instance in response when successful and raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception on failure.

Comment: I'd like both of these to be overridden by my `find` method that does exactly the same things but prints `'Overridden find called!'` additionally.

Answer (score 3):

Since `CollectionProxy` calls `find` on `CollectionAssociation` which subsequently calls `scope.find`, you don't need to do anything fancy to override:

```
module CustomFinder
  def find
    puts "I'm noisy!"
    super
  end
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  extend CustomFinder
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  extend CustomFinder
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Alternately, if you *do* want this on every model:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  extend CustomFinder
end
```

In the future you can use `foo.method(:find).source_location` and then review the relevant code on Github to get a better understanding of what's going on under the hood without wasting hours spelunking in the dark.

For another example of how to do this, [check out the way Friendly ID handles it](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/finder_methods.rb#L18-L24).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to override `find` just for the `Comment` model but at the same time being able to call the same overridden method on comments collection? What I want is:
    `Comment.find(1)` - prints `I'm noisy!`, `post.comments.find(1)` - prints `I'm noisy!`, `Post.find(1)` - doesn't print `I'm noisy!`. In the meantime I'm going to read some ActiveRecord source code to understand what exactly happens there.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that'll work. You would instead need to only override the finder on `Comment` and then change the root of your scope to use `Comment` instead of `Post`, otherwise when `CollectionAssociation` calls `find` it's going to hit `Post.find`. For example, you could do this: `Comment.where(post: post).find(1)`.

Comment: Honestly, overriding such a critical method is probably a bad idea, especially if you don't already have a strong grasp of the other elements at play here. What are you trying to achieve that this seemed like the right solution?

Comment: Yeah, I know that overriding such a critical method is like playing with fire. Actually, I'm trying to find a solution to the [problem described here](https://github.com/jcypret/hashid-rails/pull/55). It's a gem tackling the same problem as Friendly ID, which you've mentioned before.

Comment: @ahawrylak Seems like you would just use `find_by_hashid` in that case.